# How would you format DateTime in international format?

Tags: c#, datetime

The international string representation format is (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM).

e.g. 2010-06-10 21:21:10 -0400

basically the problem I am having is figuring out how to get the difference from GMT.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ????}", dt);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

will output:

```
2010-06-29 08:25:16 -07:00
```

Comment: @Aaron: The `±HH:mm` format, including a `:`, is legal in ISO8601.

Answer (score 2):

string isoFormat = inputDateTime.Format("s");

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [`ISO format`](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/iso.htm).

And the W3C has also a note on the topic: [`Date and Time Formats`](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

These are international standards.

Comment: that would probably be better but I'm trying to pass the date back and forth from objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is shown in the hours.  That -4 is the difference from GMT.

Oh I see, sorry misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> How would you format DateTime in international format?

You can use a [custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) (there is no standard formats for ISO standard date/time formats).

> the problem I am having is figuring out how to get the difference from GMT.

Parse using one of `DateTimeOffset`'s static methods, and then check the [`Offset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset.aspx) property.

Or if you mean, how to include the offset in the string: use `DateTimeOffset` with the correct timezone and a custom format specifier.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier as per Mark Dykun's answer below this works