# Unable to parse date time in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I know such questions are in ton here.  Please go through once

I have a `string` coming from textbox having current date e.g. 10/9/2012, my class property is of `DateTime?` type. I am using `Convert.ToDateTime(datetime_string_from_textbox)` but it gives me a `FormatException`. I then tried `DateTime.ParseExact(string, format, CultureInfo, DateTimeStyle)` as suggested by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime) but still it gave me the same exception.

One more thing — my local machine date time format is `dd-mm-yyyy`. When I switch this to `mm/dd/yyyy` format the code works fine. So basically , I want to know how to parse a valid datetime string to a `DateTime` object irrespective of the regional settings, or any settings or any dependency on local machine.

Is this possible?

Update : Code in use

```
employee.JoiningDate = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} 00:00:00", JoiningDate.Text.Trim()), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

**Existing Problem and  Required Solution**

My system datetime shows 24-10-2012 (that is, 24th Oct) and I have 10/17/2012 in my text box (that is, 17th Oct) since the text box date is also valid and after deployment again the client datetime format will become unknown so, I want a generic way to parse any valid datetime string irrespective of regional settings. Is this possible?

Comment: What format string did you use?

Comment: what format did you specify with DateTime.ParseExact?

Comment: use mask control and restrict the input to a specific format. Use the same format while parsing the date.

Comment: employee.JoiningDate = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} 00:00:00", JoiningDate.Text.Trim()), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

Comment: The way your machine is configured, `10/9/2012` is not a valid date format, `10-9-2012` is the valid format. What business reason do you have for wanting to parse `/` separators?

Comment: @ChristianHayter My System Date time shows 24-10-2012 that is 24th Oct and I have 10/17/2012 in my text box that is 17th oct since the text box date is also valid and after deployment again the client date time format will become unknown so , I want a generic way to parse any valid datetime string irrespective of regional settings. Is this possible

Comment: Amit, the whole point of the system-wide international settings are to define how the user intends to enter data. If the machine is configured for D/M/Y, and the user enters M/D/Y, then that is a user training issue, and not the fault of your code.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As tested bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your date to international date format using this method:

[How would you format DateTime in international format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142126/how-would-you-format-datetime-in-international-format)

Also you can check this for your current culture:

[Set Default DateTime Format c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389187/set-default-datetime-format-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the machine settings. `DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` will work for British format but it will give format exception on US format. So use format according to your machine settings.

Comment: By my knowledge, `Invariant Culture` is only based on the English Language and is not culture or region specific. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx

Comment: This is what I have experienced. Use US format and this code will work and use British format and this code will not work. Atleast it is with me.

Comment: I have tried this: `DateTime.ParseExact("24/12/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); DateTime.ParseExact("24-12-2012", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); DateTime.ParseExact("24.12.2012", "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and they all give `24-12-2012 0:00:00` So it behaves as expected, nothing wrong. My native settings are `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Comment: `12.24.2012 --> MM.dd.yyyy` and `12/24/2012 --> MM/dd/yyyy` and `12-24-2012 --> MM-dd-yyyy` same results

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if it works

```
var formatInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
formatInfo.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime.Parse(date, formatInfo);
```